# How to implement access control for arbitrary transaction data

Tags: proxy-contracts, access

Is there a contract that receives transactions, and forwards them to arbitrary other contracts, by inspecting the transaction data, i.e. target contract address, function signature, parameter values, and gates the forwarding by appropriate rule and role based access control?

For example, I want to be able to say, that this contract with this function and paramater values can only be called if certain rules and certain permissions are satisfied. I want to manage this in an outside contract, effectively refactoring the access control outside.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a perfect fit for your question, but some examples I have come across

- [Enzyme vault guard](https://github.com/enzymefinance/protocol/blob/v4/contracts/release/core/fund-deployer/FundDeployer.sol#L640-L644)
- [Zodiac guard from Gnosis](https://github.com/enzymefinance/protocol/blob/v4/contracts/release/core/fund-deployer/FundDeployer.sol#L640-L644)
- [RigoBlock guards](https://github.com/RigoBlock/v3-contracts/blob/development/contracts/protocol/extensions/adapters/AUniswap.sol)
- [DS-guard](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-guard/blob/master/src/guard.sol)